# Reading nested JSON data encoded as a nested string with Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have this weird JSON to parse containing nested JSON ... a string. So instead of

```
{\"title\": \"Lord of the rings\", \"author\": {\"666\": \"Tolkien\"}\"}"
```

I have

```
{\"title\": \"Lord of the rings\", \"author\": \"{\\\"666\\\": \\\"Tolkien\\\"}\"}"
```

Here's my (failed) attempt to parse the nested string using `decode`, inside an instance of `FromJSON` :

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Maybe
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Authors = M.Map Int String

data Book = Book
  {
    title :: String,
    author :: Authors
  }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

decodeAuthors x =  fromJust (decode x :: Maybe Authors)

instance FromJSON Book where
  parseJSON = withObject "Book" $ \v -> do
    t <- v .: "title"
    a <- decodeAuthors <?> v .: "author"
    return  $ Book t a

jsonTest = "{\"title\": \"Lord of the rings\", \"author\": \"{\\\"666\\\": \\\"Tolkien\\\"}\"}"

test = decode jsonTest :: Maybe Book
```

Is there a way to decode the whole JSON in a single pass ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple problems here.

**First**, your use of `<?>` is nonsensical. I'm going to assume it's a typo, and what you actually meant was `<$>`.

**Second**, the type of `decodeAuthors` is `ByteString -> Authors`, which means its parameter is of type `ByteString`, which means that the expression `v .: "author"` must be of type `Parser ByteString`, which means that there must be an instance `FromJSON ByteString`, but such instance doesn't exists (for reasons that escape me at the moment).

What you *actually* want is for `v .: "author"` to return a `Parser String` (or perhaps `Parser Text`), and then have `decodeAuthors` accept a `String` and convert it to `ByteString` (using [`pack`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-17.10/bytestring-0.10.12.0/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html#v:pack)) before passing to `decode`:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (pack)

decodeAuthors :: String -> Authors
decodeAuthors x = fromJust (decode (pack x) :: Maybe Authors)
```

(also note: it's a good idea to give you declarations type signatures that you think they should have. This lets the compiler point out errors earlier)

---

**Edit**:

As @DanielWagner correctly points out, `pack` may garble Unicode text. If you want to handle it correctly, use [`Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8.fromString`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-17.10/utf8-string-1.0.2/Data-ByteString-Lazy-UTF8.html) from `utf8-string` to do the conversion:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 (fromString)

decodeAuthors :: String -> Authors
decodeAuthors x = fromJust (decode (fromString x) :: Maybe Authors)
```

But in that case you should also be careful about the type of `jsonTest`: the way your code is written, its type would be `ByteString`, but any non-ASCII characters that may be inside would be cut off because of the way `IsString` works. To preserve them, you need to use the same `fromString` on it:

```
jsonTest = fromString "{\"title\": \"Lord of the rings\", \"author\": \"{\\\"666\\\": \\\"Tolkien\\\"}\"}"
```

Comment: Don't use `pack`, use a UTF-8 encoder. Being careful about the distinction between bytes and codepoints is also the reason there's no `FromJSON ByteString` instance.

Comment: @DanielWagner But doesn't `String` swallow UTF-8 codepoints anyway?

Comment: I don't know how to interpret that question. `String` is a list of Unicode codepoints. It certainly isn't limited to the first 256 codepoints, if that's the question. You ask about UTF-8 codepoints, but I don't know what that means, because "codepoint" is the term Unicode uses for talking about things independent of encoding. The compiler makes no promises about what encoding it uses for storing codepoints in memory (though in practice the only extant Haskell implementation--GHC--uses UCS-4).

Comment: Ok @DanielWagner, I added an amendment.